# How can I render xml/rss in expressjs 4.x?

Tags: xml, node.js, express, rss

I am creating a route to handle RSS feeds using the `rss` npm module.

I've generated the appropriate xml string, I just need to know how to output xml/rss using proper headers with express 4.0.

I tried this but it doesn't work, I get an empty json object:

```
res.xml(xml);
```

Answer (score 9):

Figured it out:

```
res.set('Content-Type', 'application/rss+xml');
res.send(xml);
```

Comment: 200 is the default status code so you can safely omit that from the `send` method call.

Comment: Thanks. first time I tried it threw a 500. Must have been something else. It works fine now with no `200`.